# DJANGO - form field which selects one of the class' attributes?

Tags: django, forms, models, backend

I have two classes: Topics (with the attribute "username"); and User (which has the attributes "username1", "username2", "username3").

I want that the person may chose the Topics.username from a list which contains the User.username1, User.username2, User.username3.

Example:

1- The person inputs the User.username1, User.username2, User.username3

2- The person goes to write a topic.

3- To do so, he needs to chose between the 3 usernames to post it.

Thanks a lot for any help

EDIT:

```
#UserProfile Models
class UpperCaseCharField(models.CharField):
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(UpperCaseCharField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
def pre_save(self, model_instance, add):
    value = getattr(model_instance, self.attname, None)
    if value:
        value = value.upper()
        setattr(model_instance, self.attname, value)
        return value
    else:
        return super(UpperCaseCharField, self).pre_save(model_instance, add)

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, verbose_name=_("profile"), related_name='st')
    username1 = UpperCaseCharField(validators=[RegexValidator(regex='^.{4}$', message='Length has to be 4', code='nomatch')],
            max_length=4, blank=True, unique=True)
    username2 = UpperCaseCharField(validators=[RegexValidator(regex='^.{4}$', message='Length has to be 4', code='nomatch')],
            max_length=4, blank=True, unique=True)
    username3 = UpperCaseCharField(validators=[RegexValidator(regex='^.{4}$', message='Length has to be 4', code='nomatch')],
            max_length=4, blank=True, unique=True)
```

I haven't done much with my Topic Models, so I think it's kinda unnecessary. Sorry for the delay to answer

Comment: You'll need to show a little bit of what you've tried (code) and where you're getting stuck to get some help.

Comment: Showing an example will help. How did you end up with three username-N with your User model? Django user model by default has 1 username field (or attribute)